# Como utilizar @font-face para assinaturas no gmail?

Tags: html, css, css3, gmail, css-font-face

Tentei  utilizar

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Semibold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Semibold'), url('http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.woff') format('woff');
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
    }

</style>
```

quando coloco os codigos dentro de um style dentro da head, o gmail não pega o css, porém se coloco direto dentro das tag ele funciona, só não consegui fazer funcionar o font-face, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?
Segue o resto do código:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<style type="text/css"> 
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Semibold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Semibold'), url('http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.woff') format('woff');
    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
    }

</style>
</head>
<body link="red">
    <a href="http://www.agilsoft.com.br" class="banner" style="text-decoration:none">
        <img src="http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/banner.png" style="width: 292.7px; height: auto;">
    </a>
    <p class="nome" style="font-family: Myriad Pro Semibold ,Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; margin-top: 4.7px; margin-left:1%;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold; display: inline;kerning: -60;">Vinícios S. Amaral</span>
    </p>

    <p class="cargo" style="font-family: Myriad Pro Regular ,Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;line-height: 0.2;margin-left: 2%;margin-bottom:1%;">
        <span style="display: inline;kerning: -20;" >Analista de Suporte</span>
    </p>
        <div class="icones" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin-top: 6.8px;margin-left: 1%;">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline;" href="https://www.facebook.com/agilsoftinfo/">
                <img style="border:none;display:inline;margin-left: 5px; width : 25px; height : 25px;" data-filename="fb_icon" src="http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/fb_icon.png" alt="Facebook">
            </a>

            <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline;" href="http://agilsoft.com.br">
                <img style="border:none;display:inline;margin-left: 5px; width : 25px; height : 25px;" data-filename="site_icon" src="http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/site_icon.png" alt="Skype">
            </a>

            <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline;" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/ágilsoft/">
                <img style="border:none;display:inline;margin-left: 5px; width : 25px; height : 25px;" data-filename="linkedin_icon" src="http://www.agilsoft.com.br/assinatura/linkedin_icon.png" alt="Maps">
            </a>

        </div>
    <p class="fone" style="font-family: Myriad Pro Regular ,Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9.5pt; line-height: 14px; margin-top: 6.8px; margin-left: 1%;">
        <span style="display: inline;
        kerning: -20;"> 3599-3714 / 3039-2061</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara muito provavelmente é uma questão de segurança. O Gmail não vai deixar vc adicionar um link no código, ainda mais sendo um `http`... talvez um `https` ele libere, mesmo acho acho pouco provável! No geral Clientes de Email são muito restritos quanto a customizações CSS, scripts e algumas tag HTML como `iframe`, `object` e `embed`

Veja nessa tabela que vc pode [consultar aqui](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/) que o Gmail no geral não aceita `@font-face`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]